# FadeIn element with .before Jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I fade in an element after using jquery's .before?

jQuery

```
$('.button').on("click", function(event){
   var html = '';
   html = '<div class="row new">Test</div>';

   $('.content .row:first').before(html);
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="button">Insert me and fade me</a>
<div class="content">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So when your `before` completes you want to fade in an element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('.button').on("click", function(event){
   var html = '';
   html = '<div class="row new">Test</div>';

   $('.content .row:first').before($(html).fadeIn());
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').on("click", function(event){
   var html = '<div class="row">Test</div>';
   $('.content .row:first').before(html).prev().hide().fadeIn(1000);
});​
```

The `new` class is unnecessary. You already know that the first row is the new one (and you would have to remove the class upon subsequent insertions).

Answer (score 1):

Add this line: `$('.row.new:last').hide().fadeIn();`

**jQuery**:

```
$('.button').on("click", function(event) {
    var html = '';
    html = '<div class="row new">Test</div>';
    $('.content .row:first').before(html);
    $('.row.new:first').hide().fadeIn();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KAtep/1/)**.